# networking header files in C++

Tags: networking

I'm trying to convert a c program into c++ program . what is the equivalent header file for socket.h in c++ ?

Comment: Exactly the same as the C ones.

Answer (score 2):

socket.h

Comment: With an uppercase 'S'? I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

There's no real need to change the headers at all. On the other hand, if you're just planning to use the existing code, I'd probably just add:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#extern "C" {
#endif
```

and

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

...to a header for your existing code, and leave it as C instead of re-compiling as C++.

If you're developing new code in C++, I'd consider using something like [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/), [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html), or [Boost::ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) instead of writing directly to the sockets API.

Comment: All vaguely recent C/C++ implementations will do the test for __cplusplus for you - you would have to be using a really ancient compiler version to make these tests necessary in your own code.